# @ngrx actions with multiple payloads

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am creating a web app using Angular 4 and @ngrx 4 and I am having a problem configuring strong typed actions.

I am new to @ngrx and I created the following class for my actions:

```
export const ActionTypes = {
  LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE: 'load-product-tree',
  LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE: 'load-product-tree-complete'
};

// Load product tree by Id.
export class LoadProductTreeAction implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE;
  constructor (public payload: number) { }
}

export class LoadProductTreeCompleteAction implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE;
  constructor (public payload: Map<number, Node>) { }
}

export type Actions = LoadProductTreeAction | LoadProductTreeCompleteAction;
```

However when I try to use these actions in my reducer:

```
export interface State {
  productTree: Map<number, Node>;
}

const initialState: State = {
  productTree: new Map<number, Node>()
};

export function productTreeReducer(state = initialState, action: productTreeOperations.Actions): State {

  switch (action.type) {
    case productTreeOperations.ActionTypes.LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE:
      return state;

    case productTreeOperations.ActionTypes.LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE:
      return { productTree: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

I get this error: `Type '{ productTree: number | Map<number, Node>; }' is not assignable to type 'State'. Types of property 'productTree' are incompatible. Type 'number | Map<number, Node>' is not assignable to type 'Map<number, Node>'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Map<number, Node>'.` in this line: `return { productTree: action.payload };`

How can I create a set of actions that take different payloads / arguments?

Also what would be the best practice for the return value of the `LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE` action in the reducer? Should I return the current state while the information is being loaded from the backend, or should I return something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the default Action interface of the framework, do the following refactor:

```
export const LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE = 'load-product-tree';
export const LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE = 'load-product-tree-complete';

export class LoadProductTreeAction implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE;
  constructor (public payload: number) { }
}

export class LoadProductTreeCompleteAction implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE;
  constructor (public payload: Map<number, Node>) { }
}

export type Actions = LoadProductTreeAction | LoadProductTreeCompleteAction;

export function productTreeReducer(state = initialState, action: productTreeOperations.Actions): State {

  switch (action.type) {
    case productTreeOperations.LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE:
      return state;

    case productTreeOperations.LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE:
      return { productTree: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I will later add the corresponding explanations, but basically you want typescript to recognize the `type` property as an individual type, and not as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The key to the problem is `readonly` keyword

You need to set readonly for the type of the action

Comment: Try to be more specific. If you have such a general answer then insert it into the comments and not as an answer. Read the rules, please.

Answer (score -2):

That is hard for me to read your code and guess it, but I assume that you have

```
export class Action{
    type: ActionType;
    payload: number | Map<number, Node>;
}
```

Then you have function:

```
export function productTreeReducer(state = initialState, action: productTreeOperations.Actions): State {...}
```

So your problem is related to type incompatibility.
`State` can accept only `Map<>` but you return actually `Map<> OR number`. And in this case, fact that in `LoadProductTreeCompleteAction` you provided `Map<>` in constructor doesn't matter, as `payload` value could change in runtime (externally by `setter` or internally by state change/method [even though it may not exist]).

So you have to change signature of your `State` to accept both types, of if you are sure that `LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE` always returns `Map<>`, you can try to

```
return { productTree: <Map<number, Node>>action.payload };
```

Comment: Hi, since I am sure that the `LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE` action will return a Map object, I used the type casting you suggested: `return { productTree: <Map<number, Node>>action.payload };`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thats a really bad approach. First, if you have other switch cases where you extract the information for the new state from the payload, you will need to replicate the explicit casting all over the place. Second, why would you want to define the type of payload as an union type that depends on the types that the implementations of action define for payload? that is just nonsense. @Felipe please check my answer, or take a look at the example app in the @ngrx/plattform project.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, I created this class to hold the action types following this tutorial: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/building-a-redux-application-with-angular-2-part-2#-quot-classifying-quot-actions. I think that I misunderstood it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: that guide is not meant for ngrx@4.0.0